# Complex analysis: plotting images of curves after applying complex transforms

Tags: gratis, math

We're studying complex analysis transformations in the university right now (linear fractional transformation, Joukowsky transform, exponents, their compositions, etc).

I'm looking for an application which can, given a curve in a form of either equation on complex number or equation on coordinates (like `|z-i|<2`)  and a transformation (like `w(z)=z^2+1/z`) show me what this curve will turn into after applying the transformation.

It'd also be very useful if the tool can also show which areas/points are transformed into which. Interactivity is good to have, but something like Octave with pre-written program to do that kind of plotting is also ok.

I'm looking for a software or web application which I can use for free on my personal laptop. Free license "for educational purposes" is acceptable as long as it does not require the university to have `.edu`-address, detailed transcripts or contract with the university (like MSDN AA). I'm not interested in try-before-buy or monthly subscriptions, although they may be useful for other users, so I think they worth sharing anyway.

I know about Matlab, Mathematica and they probably can do that kind of thing, but they are not free. I've also tried WolframAlpha but it looks like I cannot specify which curve or point to transform.

I'm looking for either web software, Windows software or Linux software.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the combination of [python](https://www.python.org/), [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)/[scipy](http://scipy.org/), [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) & [jupyter](http://jupyter.org/).

All of the above software elements:

- Fit together nicely
- Can produce submission ready results
- Are Free, both gratis & Open Source for personal, acedmic, professional & business use.
- Work on a variety of OS platforms
- The code can be expected to work across those platforms without modification.

You can see the sort of results that can be obtained [here](https://github.com/barbagroup/AeroPython/blob/master/lessons/06_Lesson06_Assignment.ipynb).
[image]
*The above Content under Creative Commons Attribution license CC-BY 4.0, code under MIT license (c)2015 L.A. Barba, Pi-Yueh Chuang.*